# Send email when one subscription email is added on Google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a code that collect emails from my website when someone clicks subscribe to a google sheet. The process is based on these steps here: https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets/blob/master/README.md
However I want to send also an email to the person who subscribed to my website through the google script but I am not able to do so. Here is the code:

```
 function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    
        
       var row = sheet.getLastRow()-1
       var column = sheet.getLastColumn()
       var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1,row,column)
       var data = dataRange.getValues();
       var email = data[row-1][1];
       MailApp.sendEmail("man@test.com", "Wellcome To Engineers", email);
    
    
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
    
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

if collects the emails on the list but it does not send emails to anyone

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Add the textual error message.

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstood your code, but it seems you just need to replace the `MailApp.sendEmail("man@test.com", "Wellcome To Engineers", email)` with the proper arguments - or is `man@test.com` a real email address?

Comment: Sorry bur that is just a dummy email address so I wouldn't publish my email to the whole world. The code does not send the email to me. In reality I want to reply to the subscriber so there is going to the variable email and then I will be thanking for subscribing to my website. At the moment is just for testing sending respont to me the email address.

Comment: Please provide some more details and what you have tried so far. Where do you think the problem is? Do you get any errors? Can you share an example sheet? I am sorry to ask so many questions but it is very hard to understand exactly what you want to do or how you have it set up. Right now its just a case of guessing what you may have wrong.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Intro

There are various parts to your script, but I believe the central question you are asking is about getting a `doPost()` function to send emails, so here is a snippet of an quick example I made that will work in Apps Script. It doesn't use any of the extras such as the Lock Service, or try catch blocks, and it doesn't return anything, but it does update the spreadsheet and it does send an email.

Adapt this to your needs first, then see about adding in the Lock Service, Try and Catch Blocks and Return messages.

<sup>(if you are having trouble with these extras make sure to ask **new** questions about them and not try to get an answer in this thread)</sup>

### Example Web App to Update Sheet and Send Mail on POST Request.

1. I made a new spreadsheet with only a few headers - "name", "timestamp", and "email" (this is not real data). "timestamp" needs to be written **exactly** the same (no capitals etc).

> [image: sample sheet]

2. I opened the script editor to start a container bound script (container bound to the spreadsheet).
3. I wrote this code:

```js
function doPost (e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // works if container bound
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
  var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
  
  var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
  })
  
  var newRange = sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length)
  newRange.setValues([newRow])
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter["email"], "Wellcome To Engineers", "Welcome"); // you seemed to have the order of the parameters wrong.
}
```

4. Made a `POST` request with curl from the command line to test it:

```
curl -X POST -F 'name={{name}}' -F 'email={{email}}' https://script.google.com/macros/s/{{script id}}/exec
```

This updated the spreadsheet and sent an email to the email I used in the POST request.

#### References

- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

Comment: i ve just added on top where I found the code and what process I did. So the only thing I added is to send the email 
       var row = sheet.getLastRow()-1
       var column = sheet.getLastColumn()
       var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1,row,column)
       var data = dataRange.getValues();
       var email = data[row-1][1];
       MailApp.sendEmail("man@test.com", "Wellcome To Engineers", email);

Comment: So instead of this code I pasted in your code and still the same problem I click subsribe to may website www.chatziefraimidis.com the list is updated and email is not send. The code is not wrong for testing purposes i was sending the email to myself inorder to check when it will work. When i click run the do post your code breaks at  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[hader] which is probably because is empty i suppose. Also I dont eknow how to run the curl that you mentioned. Sorry i am not very good with google scripts.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the Google Sheet that is linked to this project. In my answer I have added a screenshot of what my example looks like. You don't need to run the `curl` - its just a way to make a POST request, it should be taken care of by the website when the user presses "subscribe". Also, please look into the executions of your script to see if there are any error messages, and update your original question with that information.